# Is it possible to query on an interface property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have the following class:

```
public class BicycleSellerListing : IUserName
{
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// IUserName interface property
    /// </summary>
    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return UserProfile.UserName;
        }
    }
}
```

The interface:

```
public interface IUserName
{
    string UserName { get; }
}
```

And this query:

```
public static List<T> GetList<T>(string userName) where T : class, IUserName
{
    using (SqlUnitOfWork work = new SqlUnitOfWork())
    {
        return work.GetList<T>(row => row.UserName == userName)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

When I execute this query, I get the following exception:

> The specified type member 'UserName' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

I understand why I'm getting the exception, but am wondering if there is a way I can perform this query using the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer you quistion:

> ```
> Is it possible to query on an interface property?
> ```

Yes. it's no problem. The fault you are getting is not becuase of the interface.

The problem is that you *can't* query on properties that isn't mappe with Linq 2 Entities

[Other people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241643/how-to-use-a-custom-property-in-a-linq-to-entities-query) have had this propblem as well.

The underlying expressionbuilder can not distinct between properties that is mapped to the database, and properties that is not.

It is a problem becuase the compiler can't help you. 
In Linq to object, it is no problem, so the compiler doesnt throw any errors/warnings

You should try to make it clear the this property is not mapped - perhaps by a prefix, or a nested class that contains all the "custom" properties.

Comment: That's the case. The error message already states it: `entity members`. `UserName` is not part of the model, and therefor is not an `entity member`.

Comment: I suspect I can. Will have to get back to a desk to test this out.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answer(s), you can perform the where in memory, but that means retrieving the whole table.

Normally I wouldn't recommend this though.

```
public static List<T> GetList<T>(string userName) where T : class, IUserName
{
    using (SqlUnitOfWork work = new SqlUnitOfWork())
    {
        return work.GetList<T>()
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(row => row.UserName == userName)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would emphasize that this will retrieve the **entire** table. Depending on the size of this table this can be a **huge performance penalty**.

Answer (score 0):

Some workarounds:

- You could try to determine underlying entity type in runtime and
  then dynamically compile and invoke a generic method executing query 
  with this type.
- It is possible to assemble this query manually in runtime using
  Expression class
- You could try Entity SQL query syntax instead of Linq